# Buttons vanishing from Visual Basic Toolbar

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Microsoft Visual Basic 6 and am having trouble with the toolbar. Several buttons have recently vanished from the toolbar, and replacing them with the View->Toolbar option only worked temporarily. Now, however, the Toolbar button has disappeared off the View menu, and the Customize button has likewise vanished from the Tools menu.

Does anyone know what the problem is, or where I can find out how to correct this?

Comment: Is it a legal copy?  I have NEVER heard of buttons randomly disappearing from ANY software, let alone software that requires activation/key codes.  I could understand loaded module buttons disappearing if the module is no longer loaded, but not a 'hard coded' option such as "Customize".  Have you tried a complete re-install of VB?

Comment: @WoodE, It is a corporate installation, so I would assuredly hope so. I will ask the IT department to reinstall it if matters get much worse (the undo button has fallen off since I asked this question).

Comment: OK, I meant no offence by asking, but some unscrupulous folk on here do try the "get me free software" approach :)  I honestly have never heard of any software losing built-in menu items in over 16 years, I wouldn't have a clue where to start other than a complete re-install of the specific software.  Please keep us updated as to the progress!

Comment: @WoodE, I was not offended and I'm sorry if I sounded ratty. It is a novelty for me as well. I suspect a configuration file is being corrupted, but where one would find it I've no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By chance I came across this page... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266747/en-us which does not explain how to correct the problem but does allow you to get the missing buttons back.